# How can I implement a drag and drop interface in React with the ability to zoom in and out?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am attempting to build a web application in which one of the central features is dragging and dropping icons onto a blueprint of a map. To do this, I'm using React because I need to be able to store the positions of various objects within the blueprints in order to replicate them accurately.

So far, I have a parent component that stores an array of objects, with each object having an x and a y property. This array is passed to a Canvas component that iterates over the array and absolutely positions each one within the Canvas by setting the top and left properties to the appropriate x and y property of the respective object.

I've demonstrated the principle in this codepen: [Drag and Drop Codepen](https://codepen.io/CameronBurkholder/full/dyXXQjL).

The problem I'm having is adding the ability to zoom. The parent component stores a zoom property that is passed to the canvas, and the size of the canvas is scaled according to the zoom factor using the scale transform in CSS.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            zoom: 1, // ratio to scale canvas
            map: map // root object that stores positions of items within canvas
        }  
    }
    updatePositions(newPositions) {} // updates positions in state when element is finished dragging
    updateZoom(e) {} // updates zoom factor
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Canvas 
                    positions={this.state[...].positions} 
                    updatePositions={this.updatePositions}
                    zoom={this.state.zoom}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

The child component iterates over the positions array and renders each one.

```
class Canvas extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            index: 0
        }

        // Logic to get bounds of rendered element to calculate positions within canvas
        this.selector = React.createRef();
    }
    // Select element, set active index to track position object to update, add event listener to get new position
    selectElement(index) {
        this.setState({
             index: index,
             drag: true
        }, () => {
          document.addEventListener("mousemove", this.onMouseMove);
          document.addEventListener("mouseup", this.onMouseUp);
        });
      }
      // Track mouse within bounding box to move object
      onMouseMove(e) {
        let width = 100;
        let height = 100;
        let elements = [...this.props.operatorPositions];
        let newX = e.pageX - (width / 2);
        let newY = e.pageY - height;
        // Make sure object is within canvas
        if (newX < this.state.bounds.left) {
          newX = this.state.bounds.left - this.state.bounds.x;
        } else if (newX> this.state.bounds.right - width - this.state.bounds.x) {
          newX = this.state.bounds.right - width - this.state.bounds.x;
        } 
        if (newY < this.state.bounds.top - this.state.bounds.y) {
          newY = this.state.bounds.top - this.state.bounds.y;
        } else if (newY > this.state.bounds.bottom - height - this.state.bounds.y) {
          newY = this.state.bounds.bottom - height - this.state.bounds.y;
        }
        elements[this.state.index].x = newX;
        elements[this.state.index].y = newY;
        this.props.updatePositions(elements);
      }
      // Stop tracking mouse when object is dropped
      onMouseUp(e) {
        document.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.onMouseMove);
        document.removeEventListener("mouseup", this.onMouseUp);
        this.setState({
          drag: false
        });
      }
      // Get bounding box of canvas
      componentDidMount() {
        if (!this.state.bounds) {
          this.setState({
            bounds: this.selector.current.getBoundingClientRect()
          })
        }
      }
    render() {
        const boxes = this.props.operatorPositions.map((op, index) => {
          return <Box name={this.props.operators[index]} x={op.x} y={op.y} key={index} index={index} 
           selectElement={this.selectElement} drag={index === this.state.index && this.state.drag}/>
        });
        return (
          <div id="canvas" ref={this.selector} style={{ transform: `scale(${this.props.zoom}`}}>
            { boxes }
          </div>
        )
      }
}
```

I'm not committed to this method. As can be seen in the demo, zooming limits the area of the canvas that can be accessed, and messes with the current ability to drag and position elements in the canvas.

This question isn't so much as finding a bug as asking for help developing a method to implement zoom with the system described. I'm not hard-pressed to use the current method, but any method needs to satisfy some parameters:

- The position of all elements within the canvas can be stored and recreated
- The elements can be dragged within the canvas
- The canvas can be zoomed in or out for better visibility without affecting the movement or position of the elements relative to the background

I've simplified some of the logic in the demo because the full implementation requires several complex components, but the gist is that a root component stores the data and passes the appropriate positions to the canvas for them to display. When an object is clicked on, it specifies the index of the object positions to be updated and adds event listeners to the window to update the object position on mousemove, and remove the active object and event listener on mouseup.

Any help in developing a solution is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hey there, did you ever find a solution to this. I've just started working on a project where I'm trying to implement drag and drop into a scaled container and am experiencing similar issues to you. Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

I've developed a product that does drag drop and zoom functions.
Though this question seems old, here are things you could try

1. Try adding events to the group of elements that you need to move around (drag/drop) to be individually picked up and have their events (functions such as ondrag, ondragstart, ondragend) defined as to what they should do (i.e. your TO DO Code)?
2. Initiate the event handler in the constructor.
3. For zooming a canvas you could perform style transform.

Hope this helps.